# openvpn: Can't ping client when it's connected from inside LAN

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vpn, iptables, openvpn, networkmanager

We have an openvpn server (I beleive on our router), and mobile clients that connect to the internet from far away locations, but also occasionally from inside our office. These systems are headless so configuring them differently before connecting to the in-office network is a nonstarter - we would like to SSH into them via their avahi hostnames regardless of where they physically are.

Right we can ping and SSH when they are connected to the internet outside of our network. When they are connected from inside our LAN, sometimes `hostname.local` resolves to `192.168.10.3` (and ping and SSH don't work) and sometimes to `192.168.1.211` (and ping and ssh do work).

When monitoring wireshark on the mobile client, ping requests to the 192.168.10.3 address do appear but are not answered.

How can we configure our clients so they can be reached when connecting from inside of our network?

output of `ifconfig` on client (connected to VPN via our office LAN):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:a7:fa:e5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.223  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a45:f5b1:1b87:c6f0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1847719 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:160760 (160.7 KB)
          Interrupt:42 

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ce:d4:a6:18:48:21  
          inet addr:192.168.10.3  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ccd4:a6ff:fe18:4821/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:214474 (214.4 KB)  TX bytes:7149 (7.1 KB)
```

output of `route` on client (connected to VPN via our office LAN):

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tap0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.10.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tap0
```

Back-to-back pings from another machine on the same LAN to our mobile client. For whatever reason avahi `.local` names unpredictably resolve to the VPN IP or the other. Anyway, the ping to the VPN IP (second one) just hangs:

```
[15:51:25]~$ ping liber0.local
PING liber0.local (192.168.1.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.223: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.00 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.223: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=6.09 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.223: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=38.8 ms
^C
--- liber0.local ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.003/16.302/38.805/15.935 ms
[15:51:29]~$ ping liber0.local
PING liber0.local (192.168.10.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- liber0.local ping statistics ---
27 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 26629ms
```

OpenVPN configuration file:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote <redacted>
float
resolv-retry infinite 
nobind
persist-key 
persist-tun 
verb 3
ca <redacted>.pem 
cert <redacted>.pem
key <redacted>.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key hint was that the ICMP packets made it to the VPN connected client, but were not answered. It turned out that the default rp_filter (reverse path filter) is the strictly checking and dropping packets. adding `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` sets rp_filter to loose reverse path checking, and everything works.